# When are jobs that trigger child pipelines added to the pipeline?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml, gitlab-ci-trigger

In my gitlab CI pipeline I am generating and triggering a child pipeline like so:

```
generate-child-pipeline:
  stage: make_child_pipeline
  needs:
    - job: image-build
      optional: true
  script:
    - ./generate_pipeline.sh
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - child_pipeline-gitlab-ci.yml
  rules:
    - <assorted rules>
  tags:
  - my_tag

trigger-child-pipeline:
  stage: make_child_pipeline
  needs:
    - job: generate-child-pipeline
  trigger:
    include:
      - artifact: child_pipeline-gitlab-ci.yml
        job: generate-child-pipeline
  rules:
    - !reference [generate-child-pipeline, rules]
```

Which works fine if I ensure that conditions are such that the `rules` cause the jobs to get added to my pipeline. However, if those conditions are *not* met, it appears that the `trigger-child-pipeline` job still gets added to my pipeline (despite having exactly the same rules as `generate-child-pipeline`. And then the pipeline fails with a `yaml` error because `trigger-child-pipeline` is present in the pipeline but `generate-child-pipeline` isn't:

```
'trigger-child-pipeline' job needs 'generate-child-pipeline' job, but 'generate-child-pipeline' is not in any previous stage
```

So it seems like there is some other reason why the trigger job is getting added to my pipeline, aside from the rules I have set. What could that possibly be? Are trigger jobs just added to pipelines by default or something? I'm not sure how to get the proper behaviour out of this. My child pipeline should simply not get triggered if the rules are not met, or that was the behaviour I expected anyway. Not sure what else could logically make sense...

Edit: I tried adding

```
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE
      when: never
```

to the end of the rules for `trigger-child-pipeline`, and this did nothing. However, if I add this and delete all the other `trigger-child-pipeline` rules, then indeed `trigger-child-pipeline` doesn't get added to the pipeline and we are fine. But I have no idea what is going on, because I am using a reference to set the rules to be the same as `generate-child-pipeline`, which seems to be behaving correctly, so I don't see how one job could be added to the pipeline but not the other.

It's always tempting to blame things on gitlab-ci bugs, but that's kind of what this is feeling like. Maybe gitlab is incorrectly checking the dependencies for the trigger job before checking whether it is actually part of the pipeline, or some weird issue like that...

Comment: Could it have something to do with the fact that I am running this on a Merge Request pipeline? There is some stuff about that in https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html#run-child-pipelines-with-merge-request-pipelines, but I don't fully understand what it is saying. And my problem is not getting it to run, it is getting the trigger job to *not* run when it is not supposed to run.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured it out. Turns out I had forgotten a few things about how my `rules` worked, and actually they had some variable expansions in them. I deleted the variables from my example because I thought they weren't relevant, but they were the problem. I had them defined in one job and not the other, causing them to effectively have different rules despite how it appears on the surface.

So ok it all makes sense and trigger jobs don't do anything weird with rules, and there is no weird gitlab bug here.